# BCrypt in my Spring Security project (Spring security)

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

how can I do encryption. So that in the database it does not show the user password. I am now saved in the database - login and password, user role. I need Password must be encrypted (BCrypt)
 in the database

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/allStudents")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder weDoNotWantEncryption() {
        return new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
                return rawPassword.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
                return rawPassword.toString().equals(encodedPassword);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simply - just replace your `weDoNotWantEncryption()` function with one that returns a BCrypt instance:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

`BCryptPasswordEncoder` implements `PasswordEncoder` (as the name suggests) and so already has good methods defined for `encode()` and `matches()`.

Note that this will (of course) render any passwords currently in your database unusable, although given that those passwords are stored in plaintext, I assume (and hope/pray) that this is in a test environment, rather than production.

Comment: Bro i add your code in my file. But the passwords in my mySQL database are still visible

Comment: This will not change any existing passwords. Try adding a new password though and it should appear in the BCrypt format. Password encoders in Spring are used to hash the password **when it is put in the database**. `BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode()` is called during the database store operation, so you should not see any differences in your database. (FYI if testing, you can set your ddl to `create` to setup a new db on each run, this will avoid those errors.

Answer (score 3):

When we encrypt passwords for storage, we generally hash them so that it is a one way encryption i.e we cannot retrieve the original password from the encrypted password even if we knew the hashing algorithm.

The main procedure we follow to do this as follows.

- Take the string "password"
- Add a salt (a random string to ensure multiple users with the same password do not have the same hashed password) to the password: Random salt: "A3fcherf42", Generated string: "A3fcherf42password"
- Hash this string using an encryption algorithm and you might get: "d143d1w132dd23dsgrg5"
- Append the salt to the encrypted password for future use when validating user login: "A3fcherf42d143d1w132dd23dsgrg5"
- Save it in the database with the user id

Now to validate user login:

- Take password from the login form i.e "password"
- Read the hash stored in the database: "A3fcherf42d143d1w132dd23dsgrg5"
- Extract the salt from stored hashed password: "A3fcherf42"
- Append the salt to the user entered password: "A3fcherf42password"
- Hash the password, and now the generated hash should match the hash stored in the database.

To do this using Bcrypt is a simple process as most of the work is handled by the library. I explained the above scenario so you have a good understanding of what is happening behind the scenes. You do the following to generate and save the hashed password.

```
String pw_hash = BCrypt.hashpw(plain_password, BCrypt.gensalt());
```

Now that you have the hashed string, you store this into the database.

When the user logs in, you take his entered password, the database stored hash string, and validate it.

```
if (BCrypt.checkpw(entered_pw, stored_hash))
    return True;
```

Refer to the spring security documentation on BCrypt hashing here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html

Comment: Note - if using BCrypt, the salt is contained as part of the hash (as defined by the BCrypt spec). So there is no need to create an extra database column for your salt, since its part of the password. BCrypt will also take this into account when verifying